# Выгрузка данных из БД в JSON

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть составной запрос в БД. Нужно используя PHP вывести данные в JSON. Делаю простой запрос и получаю ошибки.

```
select id_post, id_tag from (SELECT id_t_p, id_tag,
                 @order:=IF(id_post=@snum, @order+1, 0) ord, @snum:=id_post id_post

            FROM tag_post,
                 (select @snum:=0,@order:=0) t1
            ORDER by id_post, id_t_p) t2
            where ord = 0
```

Делаю такой запрос простенький:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Ошибка соединения: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Success';

//mysql_close($link);

$data = array();

$ta = mysql_query("select id_post, id_tag from (SELECT id_t_p, id_tag,
                     @order:=IF(id_post=@snum, @order+1, 0) ord, @snum:=id_post id_post

                FROM tag_post,
                     (select @snum:=0,@order:=0) t1
                ORDER by id_post, id_t_p) t2
                where ord = 0"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ta)){                   
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Получаю такую ошибку:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\OpenServer\domains\JSON\index.php on line 20
[]
```

Comment: Я так понимаю Вы решили устроить викторину "Угадайте содержимое ошибок и строку ее вызвавшую"? В общем если захотите решить проблему, приложите их описание и минимальные тестирования(сам запрос хоть выполняется в том же phpMyAdmin).

Comment: Сам запрос выполнял в phpMyAdmin, там все работает) просто в php я новичок(

Comment: Хорошо, скорее всего $ta приходит не то, что нам нужно и запрос выполняется неправильно из самого php. Идем дальше и выполняем такой код [согласно документации](http://www.php.su/mysql_query): `$ta = mysql_query( ...тут ваш запрос ... ) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());` который выдаст на больше сведений и причине ошибки. То есть добавьте `or die("Invalid query: ".mysql_error());`

Comment: Очень хорошая подсказка, спасибо)

Comment: Не за что, в следующий раз сразу прикладывайте ошибки, в них в большинстве случаев содержится половина ответа.